# jtree make user see updates via "blinking" (rapid change of color)

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtree

I have a JTree presenting information (via DefaultMutableTreeModel).
This information is either from user actions or from asynchronous
messages over the network.
My question is, is it possible to make the text of a tree node to start "blinking" (I guess this is a rapid change of color) so that the user is alerted that something new has beed added?  If yes how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 parts of the problem.

1. Detecting recently changed nodes.
   You can add `TreeModelListener` to your model and get list of changed/inserted nodes.
2. Blinking.
   Create a custom renderer which can render the same node in two colors depending on blink state (e.g. background or foreground is swithed black to red and back). In the renderer check whether the node was changed (present in the list) and set background to red.

Add a `javax.swing.Timer` to change color each 0.5 sec, and call repaint of the nodes regions (use `getRowBounds` or `getPathBunds` method of `JTree`).

Comment: @StanislavL:I am not sure how to use getRowBounds. Could you please elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: @StanislavL: `getRowBounds` and `getPathBounds` return a `Rectangle` which does not have a repaint method

Comment: Use TreeModelEvent of your listener and getTreePath() method. Then you can either store the path(s) or row. Path can be converted to row by public int getRowForPath(TreePath path) method of JTree.

Comment: It's better to keep paths because changed path may be not visible so there is no row ( -1)

Comment: use JTree.repaint() passing the rectangle.

Comment: @StanislavL: But how do I change the color of the Rectangle? I can not find the coresponding method. I am not clear on this

Comment: @Stanislav:If I store the defaultMutableTreeNode added programmaticely in an arraylist, I get null if I call getPathBound on that node. If I call repaing on the whole tree, I see indeed blinking. But why can I not use my pre-stored in the arraylist defaultmutablenode?Do you know?

Comment: @Stanislav:Can you please check out my related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4511222/manipulate-jtree-node-via-references-seems-not-working-swing? Thanks