# manipulate jtree node via references seems not working (swing)

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jtree

I have the following problem (this is related to my post [blink a tree node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506780/jtree-make-user-see-updates-via-blinking-rapid-change-of-color)):
I have a custom cell renderer.
In some part of my code I create a new DefaultMutableTreeNode and store it in a list

```
public static List<DefaultMutableTreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<DefaultMutableTreeNode>() 
//in some time
DefaultMutableTreeNode aNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("SomeValue");
nodes.add(node);
```

In my cell renderer I do:

```
public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value,
      boolean selected, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row,
      boolean hasFocus) {
    DefaultMutableTreeNode n = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)value;
    if(nodes.contains(n)){
     //set background to red
    }
}
```

At this point nodes has a node but the code never goes in the if branch.
Why? I can not understand since I already stored it in the arraylist. Do I get a different reference?
Also I created a swing timer:

```
Timer t = new Timer(400, new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        if(nodes.size == 0)
            return;
        TreePath p = new TreePath(nodes.get(0));
        Rectangle r = tree.getPathBounds(p);
        tree.repaint(r);
   }

});
```

But I get a NPE in `tree.getPathBounds`.
I can not understand why. Can't I manipulate DefaultMutableNodes I stored in my list this way? What am I doing wrong in my thinking?
Note: If I simply call repaint(); in the timer and in the cell renderer I loop over the nodes to see if it displays the sametext with the node I have stored, what I want I get the blinking, works

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `TreePath` is a list of objects... path from tree root to the node. If you create a path from the single node the path exists in the tree only if the node is root of the tree.
I woul recommend to use `TreeSelectionEvent public TreePath[] getPaths()` method. The method provides actual paths.

Comment: So if I have a list of `DefaultMutableTreeNodes` stored and I want for each to get the corresponding rectangle (in my swing timer) to repaint, how do I get it? Because it seems that the only way is via creating a `TreePath` from the stored node and then calling the `getPathBounds` but this is not working (as mentioned in my post). So how can I get the rectangle of the stored nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think DefaultMutableTreeNode defines an equals method, so it might not find the match in your List of nodes.  Try storing and searching for the user object or extends DefaultMutableTreeNode and define equals.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense. But what about the NPE dor the treePath?

Comment: Not sure.  Does tree.repaint() work?  Is it just getting the bounds that is the problem?